# Can we give user permission to add Notes & Attachments even user's profile has Read only for that object

Tags: security, attachment, tasks

I have a below setting for the object.

ORG wide defaults- Private

User's Profile - Read, View All

Can I have user to add notes and attachments despite the fact he can't edit object.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to give user adding notes permission through permission set

Comment: Are you using the old-style Notes and Attachments, or Enhanced Notes/Content Files?

Comment: Thanks David. We are using Old-Style Notes and Attachments